# How to remove configuration profiles (.mobileconfig files) using MDM?

Tags: ios, mobile-device-management, configuration-profiles

I am trying to remove a configuration profile that I previously installed on a device, using MDM. I am able to get the list of the installed profiles using the `ProfileList` command. I have no issues when trying to remove an old `.mobileconfig` file on a supervised device, but when I attempt to remove the same `.mobileconfig` file on a non-supervised device, I get the following error: `The profile “xxxx” is not managed by MDM.`

Despite this, Apple's documentation states that removing profiles using MDM is only possible if the profile has been installed through MDM (which is not the case for supervised devices).

My Question is: Is there a way to remove an old configuration profile that I previously installed on a non-supervised device that also hasn't been installed through MDM, using MDM? (to me, it makes sense that I should be able to, because at the end of the day, I distributed that profile on other people's devices and I am the owner of that `.mobileconfig` file...)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Distribute the same profile with identifier say 'apple.mdm.MyProfile1' through MDM and remove the same identifier using RequestType `RemoveProfile`.